# ConfigurationManager.GetSection Skips Duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configuration-files

Long story short, the .Net `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` method skips duplicates, and I'm looking for a best practice for handling this.  I have a config file that includes something like this:

```
   <views>
     <view name="BusinessUnitsView" Desc="desc1"/>
     <view name="BusinessUnitsView" Desc="desc2"/>
   </views>
```

I have a graph of objects the config loads onto where collections derive from our derived version of `ConfigurationElementCollection`.  The views collection in the graph only has one item in it after loading the above--my understanding is that this is simply the way the `ConfigurationManager` handled duplicates.  The last item with the same key wins.

I could throw an exception on a duplicate being found by using BaseAdd(element, true).  However, if possible I'd like to get the object completely loaded WITH duplicates, as the config gets read in a service layer, and I'd like to detect and deal with the problem on the consuming side of the service.

Do I have any options for modifying the way adds to the collection work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create your own `ConfigurationSection`.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/namevaluemultiple.aspx) (the second link's method has been deprecated, but it may still shed some light)

This allows you to represent internal configuration variables as collections, and set properties like `DefaultValue` and `IsRequired`.

Comment: As an aside, it's a bug that it doesn't support duplicates... I understand that the internal variables for the default config section handlers use NameValueCollections, and are supposed to concatenate multiple values in a comma-separated string.  I don't know why they don't, but I've had the same problem.

Comment: I think it's on purpose, last one counts. Think about Machine.config

Comment: It makes sense to have made it act that way on purpose... it's just odd that the documentation always says when you add multiple values for keys you get a comma-delimited list of values.  Maybe that idea was scrapped, but the documentation never updated?

Comment: James, I'm not too familiar with the docs. But when I look at the sample XML I can only think: You don't want that. Name is about the same as ID here.

Comment: I agree, as written, multiple values doesn't make sense... I can see situations where you would want multiple values, though.  In any case, the OP wants to read multiple values... and the customer is always right ; )

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you only want to iterate over a list but the main idea of the config is that you can do

```
var view = SomeConfigClass["BusinessUnitsView"];
```

That only allows one answer.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say there will be more than one value for the setting... there's will only be one value, a string.  What it says is that that string will be a comma-separated list of all the values you've set.  I can see all sorts of issues with that; maybe that's why they didn't do it?