# Looping through AppConfig file

Tags: c#, loops

I have an AppConfig file like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="TableSettings">
      <section name="TableNames" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <TableSettings>
    <TableNames>
      <add key="Tablename" value="DailyBilling_20131231"/>
      <add key="Tablename" value="DailyBilling_20130131"/>
    </TableNames>
  </TableSettings>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to loop through TableSettings/TableNames and get the key-value pairs.

I tried this but I am getting only the second entry. i.e. key as Tablename and value as DailyBilling_20130131.

```
var _tablenamelist = (ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TableSettings/TableNames") as System.Collections.Hashtable);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see this answer for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796258/configurationmanager-getsection-skips-duplicates

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
        try
        {
            string strXML = File.ReadAllText("xml.xml");

            XDocument xsrcdoc = XDocument.Parse(strXML);

            var KeyValuePairs = (from xml in xsrcdoc.Descendants("add") select 
                                 new {
                                     Key = xml.Attribute("key").Value,
                                     value = xml.Attribute("value").Value
                                 }).ToList();
        } //Put a break-point here and mouse-over KeyValuePairs and you should see your values....
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

I am reading your XML into a string from a file (xml.xml) in the application build folder. For the code to work, set strXML to your XML or create the xml.xml File and save you XML in it....